# Python :get possibilities of lists and change the number of loops

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops

I'd like to be able to change the number of loops and store all possibilities in a (list of lists). Let me explain by an example:

You have the following list:

```
 initial_list=[1,2]
```

Then you have a parameter n, which is the number of loops

For example if n=2, I'd like my programm to return this list:

```
 final_list=[[x,x,1,2],[x,1,x,2],[x,1,2,x],[1,x,x,2],[1,x,2,x][1,2,x,x]]
```

So for n=3, the program would do the same with 3 'x', etc

Also, i'd like my initial_list could have different length, like [1,2,3] or [1,2,3,4], etc

I know how to do that if the parameter n is hardcoded ( by n loop) but is it possible to do that if n change?

Thanks and sorry for my bad explaination ^^

Comment: You probably want `itertools.permutations` except that, since you don't seem to want all possible orderings of the `x` item, you can call `set` on it at the end (as long as `initial_list` has no duplicates; otherwise you'll have to filter manually).

Comment: Ah, but the items from `initial_list` should remain in the same order?

Comment: @Nathan I think that would not be a good approach, with `n=7` you'd have 9! lists, but you'd only want 45

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a recursive function:

```
def get_lists(lst, n, sol):
    if len(lst) == 0 and n == 0:
        return [sol]
    solutions = []
    if len(lst) > 0:
        solutions += get_lists(lst[1:], n, sol + [lst[0]])
    if n > 0:
        solutions += get_lists(lst, n - 1, sol + ['x'])
    return solutions

n = 2
initial_list = [1, 2]
print(get_lists(initial_list, n, []))
>>> [[1, 2, 'x', 'x'], [1, 'x', 2, 'x'], [1, 'x', 'x', 2], ['x', 1, 2, 'x'], ['x', 1, 'x', 2], ['x', 'x', 1, 2]]
```

The way it works:

1. You input your original list and number of x's `n`, as well as an empty list as the original 'solution'
2. It checks if either the length of your list, or n is larger than 0
3. If not, it returns the current solution
4. Otherwise, it adds onto the solution, and goes back to step 2

This is slightly more complicated than the permutations idea, however, when your list or n becomes large, this will be much faster because you won't have to worry about removing doubles.

Answer (score 1):

Use `itertools.permutations`:

```
import itertools

def permutations(initial_list, n, x):
    return list(itertools.permutations(initial_list + [x] * n))
```

Comment: Mutating `initial_list` is probably not desirable; you can avoid that and make the code simpler by doing `itertools.permutations(initial_list + [x] * n)`. Your function ought to take `x` as an input too (and there might be other discrepancies with what OP is actually looking for here).

Comment: Your solution also has a bunch of doubles and does not maintain the order of the initial list

Answer (score 0):

You could let `itertools.combinations` give you indexes where to insert `'x'`:

```
for indexes in combinations(range(len(initial_list) + n), n):
    tmp = initial_list[:]
    for i in indexes:
        tmp.insert(i, 'x')
    print(tmp)
```

Output:

```
['x', 'x', 1, 2]
['x', 1, 'x', 2]
['x', 1, 2, 'x']
[1, 'x', 'x', 2]
[1, 'x', 2, 'x']
[1, 2, 'x', 'x']
```