# Writing a faster implementation for insert() in python

Tags: python

Essentially, I need to write a faster implementation as a replacement for insert() to insert an element in a particular position in a list.
The inputs are given in a list as [(index, value), (index, value), (index, value)]

For example: Doing this to insert 10,000 elements in a 1,000,000 element list takes about 2.7 seconds

```
def do_insertions_simple(l, insertions):
    """Performs the insertions specified into l.
    @param l: list in which to do the insertions.  Is is not modified.
    @param insertions: list of pairs (i, x), indicating that x should
        be inserted at position i.
    """
    r = list(l)
    for i, x in insertions:
        r.insert(i, x)
    return r
```

My assignment asks me to speed up the time taken to complete the insertions by 8x or more

My current implementation:

```
def do_insertions_fast(l, insertions):
    """Implement here a faster version of do_insertions_simple """
    #insert insertions[x][i] at l[i]
    result=list(l)
    for x,y in insertions:
      result = result[:x]+list(y)+result[x:]
    return result
```

Sample input:

```
import string
l = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
insertions = [(0, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (2, 'b'), (7, 'c')]
r1 = do_insertions_simple(l, insertions)
r2 = do_insertions_fast(l, insertions)
print("r1:", r1)
print("r2:", r2)
assert_equal(r1, r2)

is_correct = False
for _ in range(20):
    l, insertions = generate_testing_case(list_len=100, num_insertions=20)
    r1 = do_insertions_simple(l, insertions)
    r2 = do_insertions_fast(l, insertions)
    assert_equal(r1, r2)
    is_correct = True
```

The error I'm getting while running the above code:

```
r1: ['a', 0, 'b', 'b', 1, 2, 3, 'c', 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
r2: ['a', 0, 'b', 'b', 1, 2, 3, 'c', 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-54e0c44a8801> in <module>()
     12     l, insertions = generate_testing_case(list_len=100, num_insertions=20)
     13     r1 = do_insertions_simple(l, insertions)
---> 14     r2 = do_insertions_fast(l, insertions)
     15     assert_equal(r1, r2)
     16     is_correct = True

<ipython-input-7-b421ee7cc58f> in do_insertions_fast(l, insertions)
      4     result=list(l)
      5     for x,y in insertions:
----> 6       result = result[:x]+list(y)+result[x:]
      7     return result
      8     #raise NotImplementedError()

TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

The file is using the nose framework to check my answers, etc, so if there's any functions that you don't recognize, its probably from that framework.

I know that it is inserting the lists right, however it keeps raising the error "float object is not iterable"

I've also tried a different method which did work (sliced the lists, added the element, and added the rest of the list, and then updating the list) but that was 10 times slower than insert()

I'm not sure how to continue

edit: I've been looking at the entire question wrong, for now I'll try to do it myself but if I'm stuck again I'll ask a different question and link that here

Comment: `list(y)` tries to iterate `y` to create a list out of it. You want to just do `[y]` to turn `y` into a single-element list.

Comment: I'll tell you for certain right now that your method is not faster than `insert` :)

Comment: So then is there any other way that I can implement it?

Comment: At the moment, all you are doing is creating a bulkier and more expensive version of `insert`. It's key to realize *how* `insert` works. In CPython at least, `list`s are contiguous data structures, meaning `insert` is an expensive operation. If you understand C, see https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/listobject.c#L286
`insert` calls a method `list_resize` that sometimes performs a very expensive reallocation. HTH.

Comment: BTW, the reallocations are one concern (I overstated the importance), but the idea of resizing only once doesn't help when it comes to the copying of elements. In the function linked above, you need to "shift" existing elements to make space for the new one. This "shifting" process is highly time-consuming.

Comment: @iz_ So what would be the best way to approach this (if there is any other way) that would speed up the process?

Comment: If you want fast, arbitrary insertions, you need a different data structure (like a doubly-linked list).

Comment: @chepner I'd agree with that if they weren't given all insertion requests at once.

Comment: @HeapOverflow That's doesn't really matter. It's a relatively small number of insertions into a large list.

Comment: @chepner Not sure what you mean. Getting all requests at once does matter, as it allows the solution outlined in my answer, which only uses a list, and whose rough implementation by iz_ was measured by kaya3 to be ~51 times faster.

Comment: Those aren't insertions; you're just rebuilding the list from scratch.

Comment: @chepner So I guess since `list.insert` might rebuild a list from scratch because its capacity is exhausted, `list.insert` also isn't inserting?

Comment: That's internal memory allocation; it's still the same `list` object that's shuffling some memory around. Your approach creates a new `list` object altogether.

Comment: @chepner Well then I'll just finish with `a[:] = b` so it's also the same `list` object.

Comment: @HeapOverflow Except now, you've unnecessarily copied almost the entire list in the case where all the insertion points were near the end of the list.

Comment: @chepner Can easily be optimized to work only on the part starting at the lowest insertion index. Doesn't change the principle.

Answer (score 3):

From your question, emphasis mine:

> I need to write a faster implementation as a replacement for insert() to insert **an** element in a particular position in a list

You won't be able to. If there was a faster way, then the existing insert() function would already use it. Anything you do will not even get close to the speed.

What you *can* do is write a faster way to do **multiple** insertions.

Let's look at an example with two insertions:

```
>>> a = list(range(15))
>>> a.insert(5, 'X')
>>> a.insert(10, 'Y')
>>> a
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 'X', 5, 6, 7, 8, 'Y', 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
```

Since every insert shifts all values to the right of it, this in general is an O(m*(n+m)) time algorithm, where n is the original size of the list and m is the number of insertions.

Another way to do it is to build the result piece by piece, taking the insertion points into account:

```
>>> a = list(range(15))
>>> b = []
>>> b.extend(a[:5])
>>> b.append('X')
>>> b.extend(a[5:9])
>>> b.append('Y')
>>> b.extend(a[9:])
>>> b
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 'X', 5, 6, 7, 8, 'Y', 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
```

This is O(n+m) time, as all values are just copied once and there's no shifting. It's just somewhat tricky to determine the correct piece lengths, as earlier insertions affect later ones. Especially if the insertion indexes aren't sorted (and in that case it would also take O(m log m) additional time to sort them). That's why I had to use `[5:9]` and `a[9:]` instead of `[5:10]` and `a[10:]`

(Yes, I know, `extend`/`append` internally copy some more if the capacity is exhausted, but if you understand things enough to point that out, then you also understand that it doesn't matter :-)

Comment: This is almost certainly the intended solution. However, if the insertion indices aren't sorted then it's going to take O(n + m log m) time because you need to sort them, but also sorting them is going to be tricky because insertions are not commutative, so you actually need to insert at different indices if you do the insertions in a different order.

Comment: Right, I ignored the sorting time. I guess because I'm still hoping that they *are* sorted and they're just overlooking that in the problem specification. I'll mention it. And yes, the insertions affect each other, that's why my demo already slice to/from index 9, not 10. And it's what I meant with being tricky.

Comment: Indeed. I think your answer is good (so I upvoted), I just thought that part could be expanded on.

Comment: Yes, this is the right approach. I transcribed your ideas into code [here](https://pastebin.com/P8JmR4WB) if you wanted to incorporate it into your answer.

Comment: @kaya3 I expanded a bit on it now, also fixed the naive way's complexity (it's not O(nm) if m is much larger than n). Btw, I actually *exploited* that insertions affect each other in [another case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59830093/12671057) and I'm quite please with it :-)

Comment: @iz_ Yeah, I had started writing something like that, but then with the uncertainty of whether the indexes are sorted I didn't feel like it. Yours also has a bug even for sorted insertions, try `insertions = [(0, 'a'), (0, 'b')]`.

Comment: Nice eye! Well, you could preprocess `insertions` to reverse sequences where the indices are the same or add a case in the function when the current index is equal to the previous index (or indices!) and `insert` the element however many elements off the end. Anyway, somebody's code wouldn't have made it past QA :)

Comment: @iz_ Yes, preprocessing the insertions is probably the way to go. Especially if the indexes aren't given sorted. I rather suspect that this *must* be an existing problem on some of the coding sites out there, and if that was provided, I might actually implement it.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use a different data structure, which supports faster insertions.

The obvious suggestion would be a binary tree of some sort. You can insert nodes into a balanced binary tree in O(log n) time, so long as you're able to find the right insertion point in O(log n) time. A solution to that is for each node to store and maintain its own subtree's cardinality; then you can find a node by index without iterating through the whole tree. Another possibility is a [skip list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list), which supports insertion in O(log n) average time.

However, the problem is that you are writing in Python, so you have a major disadvantage trying to write something faster than the built-in `list.insert` method, because that's implemented in C, and Python code is a lot slower than C code. It's not unusual to write an O(log n) algorithm in Python that only beats the built-in O(n) implementation for very large n, and even n = 1,000,000 may not be large enough to win by a factor of 8 or more. This could mean a lot of wasted effort if you try implementing your own data structure and it turns out not to be fast enough.

I think the expected solution for this assignment will be something like Heap Overflow's answer. That said, there is another way to approach this question which is worth considering because it avoids the complications of working out the correct indices to insert at if you do the insertions out of order. My idea is to take advantage of the efficiency of `list.insert` but to call it on shorter lists.

---

If the data is still stored in Python lists, then the `list.insert` method can still be used to get the efficiency of a C implementation, but if the lists are shorter then the `insert` method will be faster. Since you only need to win by a constant factor, you can divide the input list into, say, 256 sublists of roughly equal size. Then for each insertion, insert it at the correct index in the correct sublist; and finally join the sublists back together again. The time complexity is O(nm), which is the same as the "naive" solution, but it has a lower constant factor.

To compute the correct insertion index we need to subtract the lengths of the sublists to the left of the one we're inserting in; we can store the cumulative sublist lengths in a [prefix sum array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_sum), and update this array efficiently using `numpy`. Here's my implementation:

```py
from itertools import islice, chain, accumulate
import numpy as np

def do_insertions_split(lst, insertions, num_sublists=256):
    n = len(lst)
    sublist_len = n // num_sublists
    lst_iter = iter(lst)
    sublists = [list(islice(lst_iter, sublist_len)) for i in range(num_sublists-1)]
    sublists.append(list(lst_iter))
    lens = [0]
    lens.extend(accumulate(len(s) for s in sublists))
    lens = np.array(lens)

    for idx, val in insertions:
        # could use binary search, but num_sublists is small
        j = np.argmax(lens >= idx)
        sublists[j-1].insert(idx - lens[j-1], val)
        lens[j:] += 1

    return list(chain.from_iterable(sublists))
```

It is not as fast as @iz_'s implementation (linked from the comments), but it beats the simple algorithm by a factor of almost 20, which is sufficient according to the problem statement. The times below were measured using [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) on a list of length 1,000,000 with 10,000 insertions.

```
simple -> 2.1252768037122087 seconds
iz -> 0.041302349785668824 seconds
split -> 0.10893724981304054 seconds
```

Note that my solution still loses to @iz_'s by a factor of about 2.5. However, @iz_'s solution requires the insertion points to be sorted, whereas mine works even when they are unsorted:

```py
lst = list(range(1_000_000))
insertions = [(randint(0, len(lst)), "x") for _ in range(10_000)]

# uncomment if the insertion points should be sorted
# insertions.sort()

r1 = do_insertions_simple(lst, insertions)
r2 = do_insertions_iz(lst, insertions)
r3 = do_insertions_split(lst, insertions)

if r1 != r2: print('iz failed') # prints
if r1 != r3: print('split failed') # doesn't print
```

Here is my timing code, in case anyone else wants to compare. I tried a few different values for `num_sublists`; anything between 200 and 1,000 seemed to be about equally good.

```py
from timeit import timeit

algorithms = {
    'simple': do_insertions_simple,
    'iz': do_insertions_iz,
    'split': do_insertions_split,
}
reps = 10

for name, func in algorithms.items():
    t = timeit(lambda: func(lst, insertions), number=reps) / reps
    print(name, '->', t, 'seconds')
```

Comment: Ok, that sounds like what I expected (and I guess you, too). If numpy and list.insert were equally fast, then about sqrt(n)=1000 should be best, but since shifting memory around is likely still faster, somewhat smaller numbers should be better.

Comment: Indeed, you caught me between edits, I was already going for it! I think sqrt(n) should be an overestimate also because we do `argmax` in the loop as well as `+= 1` on the array. But thinking about it, we could dynamically choose `num_sublists` to be some constant multiple of `int(sqrt(n))`, and then the time complexity is O(n + m sqrt(n)) which does beat the naive algorithm asymptotically.

Answer (score 1):

`list(y)` attempts to iterate over `y` and create a list of its elements. If `y` is an integer, it will not be iterable, and return the error you mentioned. You instead probably want to create a list literal containing `y` like so: `[y]`

Comment: Thank you! I changed list(y) to [y] and its not throwing any errors anymore, however, like iz_ said its not faster than the insert() function

Comment: Without doing some major trickery, or mostly re-defining your problem, you're unlikely to get any faster than the built-in: `insert`. Any speed-up is going to come from taking a more efficient approach, not speeding up a slow one.

Comment: So is there a more efficient approach that I can take to speed it up? 
(Like heap overflow pointed out, if the question didnt explain it properly, I need a faster way to insert multiple elements and not a single one)